# two mono audio streams , play one on the right speaker the other on the left speaker in parallel

Tags: javascript, audio, stream

I have two mono audio streams (mp3 files) which I want to play in parallel,  right.mp3 should only be heard on the right channel (speaker) and left.mp3 only on the left channel (speaker).  How can I do this? 
I had already tried a merger see below.

```
var contextL = new AudioContext() || new webkitAudioContext(),
    requestL = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requestL.open("GET", "./left.mp3", true);
    requestL.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    requestL.onload = function(){
        contextL.decodeAudioData(requestL.response, onDecodedL);
    }

var contextR = new AudioContext() || new webkitAudioContext(),
    requestR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    requestR.open("GET", "./right.mp3", true);
    requestR.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    requestR.onload = function(){
        contextR.decodeAudioData(requestR.response, onDecodedR);
    }


function onDecodedL(buffer){
    var bufferSourceL = contextL.createBufferSource();
        bufferSourceL.buffer = buffer;
    var splitterL   = contextL.createChannelSplitter(2);
        bufferSourceL.connect(splitterL);
    var mergerL     = contextL.createChannelMerger(2);
    var gainL       = contextL.createGain();
        gainL.value = 0;
        splitterL.connect(gainL, 0);
        bufferSourceL.start();
}   

function onDecodedR(buffer){
    var bufferSourceR = contextR.createBufferSource();
        bufferSourceR.buffer = buffer;  
    var splitterR = contextR.createChannelSplitter(2);
        bufferSourceR.connect(splitterR);
    var mergerR = contextR.createChannelMerger(2);
    var gainR = contextR.createGain();
        gainR.value = 0;
        splitterR.connect(gainR,1);
        bufferSourceR.start();
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: its javascript.